# Datsac Cassandra binding with Apache Cassandra

Tags: hbase, bigdata, amazon-dynamodb, cassandra-2.0, bigtable

I am tryng to use the Datsax Cassandra (community endition) , but not able to figure out the  Datasax git repo for the same .

Can someone please help me out in figuring out which release of apache cassandra is used by Datasax cassandra (Community edition ) ??? or does datasax maintains its own private repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think apache cassandra is what  DataStax using https://github.com/apache/cassandra
DataStax is maining developing drivers for cassandra.

Comment: thanks , i myself verified its the apache github where they are making the code commits (community edition)